# ScrollView does not work inside position: absolute on Android

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

ScrollView does not work inside position: absolute on Android.

```
   <View style={{ height: 300, paddingTop: 100 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'relative',
            height: 40,
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
          }}>
          <View
            style={{
              height: 60,
              position: 'absolute',
              width: '100%',
              borderColor: 'green',
              borderWidth: 1,
              zIndex: 1000,
              elevation: 1000,
            }}>
            <ScrollView>
              <Text>1</Text>
              <Text>2</Text>
              <Text>3</Text>
              <Text>4</Text>
              <Text>5</Text>
              <Text>6</Text>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Scrolling works on iOS.
https://snack.expo.dev/3enX3_UHW

Comment: It works, please check it again

Comment: It's not working. On the web in snack it works, but in the emulator or on a real device it doesn't work.

Comment: are you new in React Native? `react-native-gesture-handler` is the most popular library you should use. If you dont want to use other library, you must write down to your question

Comment: have you found any solution to that? using ScrollView from gesture handler works for me but not if it's inside Modal